Question about layer 2 systems on the internet
this is a follow up question for an answer on a previous post I made (mod deleted it so I can’t reply on the post):
I made a post about arp being pointless
in router to router communication in the internet because they are layer 3 and use IP. Someone replied and said ”IP is a layer-3 protocol. It passes between systems on a layer-2 protocol.”
Im not sure what this means. What “systems” do packets travel through on the internet that are layer 2? Every video I’ve watched said internet traffic goes only from router to router (routers are layer 3 and use ip, yes?)

layer-2 protocols communicate between hosts on the same network, while layer-3 protocols communicate between different networks.

@RonMaupin so that goes back to my original question. Why are layer 2 mac addresses needed in the layer 3, ip based communication between different networks? It seems like I can’t find a clear answer for this

Because directly connected routers are hosts that share a network, and IPv4 on an IEEE protocol uses ARP to translate layer-3 to layer-2 addressing so that the packets on one router can traverse the shared network to any other hosts on the same network, including another router.

(this being the internet, here's the required car analogy) This is like saying, if we all have cars, why do we still need roads?

Routers are hosts, too. Routing happens at layer-3, but routers, like other hosts, use layer-1 to physically connect to other hosts, and that layer-1 needs a layer-2 protocol to frame the packets to be delivered on the layer-1 medium.
Directly connected routers share layer-1 and layer-2 protocols in order to be able to send layer-3 packets between them by encapsulating the layer-3 packets into layer-2 frames that can be sent across the layer-1 medium.
There are many different layer-1 media that can use various layer-2 protocols. Layer-3 packets do not know or care which layer1/2 protocols carry their packets, nor do layer-2 protocols care which layer-3 packets are carried by them.
Routers are variously called routers, gateways, or intermediate systems, but their purpose is to route, at layer-3, packets between different layer-3 networks, and those networks can be of different layer-1/2 protocols.
The layers allow changing different protocols at different layers and the other layers do not know or care.
Routers with Ethernet and Wi-Fi for the LAN protocols can communicate with other routers (in fact more than one other router) using Ethernet, PPP, frame relay, token ring, FDDI, HDLC, ARCNET. ATM, etc. Some use MAC addressing (requiring ARP), others use other addressing (no ARP) and some use no addressing (no ARP). ARP is a protocol used by IPv4 and IEEE protocols. IPv6 does not use ARP, it uses something else to accomplish the function of ARP and other things.

thank you sir. Now I know arp and mac isn’t a necessity in all cases for routers to communicate. You cleared things up for me
